# What is the correct order? Should it be Round -> Cast or Cast -> Round

Tags: sql, sql-server

What should be the correct order when I am trying to round?

```
   ,CAST(ROUND(COUNT(FIRE_SAFETY.DATE_COMPLETED) * 100.0 / COUNT(FIRE_SAFETY.EESS_ID),2) as  decimal(16,2)) AS Percentage
   ,ROUND(CAST(COUNT(FIRE_SAFETY.DATE_COMPLETED) * 100.0 / COUNT(FIRE_SAFETY.EESS_ID) as decimal(16,2)),2) AS Percentage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you need answer to two decimal places, you should just use cast to decimal(n,2).**

COUNT() function returns integer. When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence.

So any operation with 100.0 results to implicit decimal conversion to 100.0 type i.e. with decimal position.

So below statement should be sufficient

```
 ,CAST(COUNT(FIRE_SAFETY.DATE_COMPLETED) * 100.0 / COUNT(FIRE_SAFETY.EESS_ID) as decimal(16,2)) AS Percentage
```

See **[this MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** on how precision and scale gets impacted in SQL server based on combination types in an expression.

Also **[another mSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** on the precedence rules.

Comment: What if we want to make a calculation with more accuracy, and the result get with less accuracy?

Comment: accuracy is kind of sealed when we were multiplying int (from count) with 100.0 and dividing by int again. That is where we get everything. Everything after is just changing precision and scale or showing more or less

Comment: Right, for this example. However, I tried to focus on the question: What is the correct order? Should it be Round -> Cast or Cast -> Round @DhruvJoshi :)

Comment: See this link about precision[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017] Rounding does not change precision. If you do casting, you automatically round data as in `select cast(10.389 as decimal(10,2))` gives 10.39

Comment: Look : `SELECT ROUND(748.58, -3) `                                                                                       Next look : `SELECT ROUND(CAST (748.58 AS decimal (6,2)),-3)` @DhruvJoshi

Comment: Explanation : Results in an arithmetic overflow, because 748.58 defaults to decimal(5,2), which cannot return 1000.00.

Comment: The example I posted in comment was related to an example showing that decimal conversion implicitly supports rounding. In the current question OP can obtain sufficient precision based on multiplication with 100.0. Intent is to get percentage with two decimal figures. So precision of  5 is required at the most.

Comment: You're right, it does not change the precision, but it can significantly change the result. In the given example this does not matter, here the use of cast, round is pointless. @DhruvJoshi, So I vote for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing as long as you are rounding up to the same amount of decimals as the scale of the decimal conversion.

Converting to `DECIMAL` with lower scale automatically rounds the last digit.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), '1.009'), -- 1.01
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), '1.005'), -- 1.01
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), '1.004'), -- 1.00
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), '1.001') -- 1.00
```

Rounding after converting to decimal (with the same amount of decimals) is pointless while converting to decimal after rounding will just reduce it's scale.

```
DECLARE @BigDecimal DECIMAL(30,10) = '1.123456789'

SELECT
    Original = @BigDecimal,                                                 -- 1.1234567890
    Rounded = ROUND(@BigDecimal, 2),                                        -- 1.1200000000
    RoundedThenDecimal = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), ROUND(@BigDecimal, 2)),     -- 1.12
    Decimal = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), @BigDecimal),                         -- 1.12
    DecimalThenRounded = ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), @BigDecimal), 2)     -- 1.12
```

**Conclusion**: just cast to decimal with the scale you need and forget about rounding.

Answer (score 1):

First we should convert/cast and then round. 
From documentation for ROUND :

ROUND ( **numeric_expression** , length [ ,function ] )